# I can't install Phusion Passenger to run Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

The problem is simple.

I use the following command to install Passenger

> passenger-install-nginx-module

When Passenger automatically installs nginx, I can't launch it.

> nginx -v

Returns there's no nginx installed.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that passenger-install-nginx-module asks you where to install Nginx to? The nginx binary is in there. Make sure the appropriate directory is in your $PATH. If you don't know what $PATH is or how to use it then you should read a book about basic Unix/Linux command line skills.

Comment: I think this is most likely the issue - if `nginx -v` can't find Nginx, that means it's not in the `$PATH`, not that it's not installed.

Comment: You are right. I installed it to  /usr/local/nginx and updated $PATH. It woks now.

Answer (score 0):

You need install Nginx. the webserver.

If you use passenger 3 in standalone, you just need launch `passenger start` command

Comment: But itPassenger takes care of dowloading the source of nginx and compiling it. It says that in order to install the Passenger module, nginx has to be configured from scratch.

Comment: And when I run passenger start, I get "Nginx core 0.8.52 isn't installed"

Answer (score 0):

I solved this.

Actually, Passenger did install nginx, it just wasn't in the default category.

I recommend to tell passenger to install nginx in **/usr/local/nginx**